# speechSynthesis.speak() doesn`t output any sound

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, speech-synthesis

I am trying to create a website that scrapes a news website and reads it.
For some reason, whenever I am trying to read the actual info of the article, it reads part of it and stops after a few seconds.

important to point out :

1. I am using chromium.
2. The text I'm inserting doesn't reach speechSynthesis.speak()
   text limit.

My function :

```
export async function textToSpeech(text) {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.voice = voices[6];
    msg.lang = "en";
    msg.text = text;
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    msg.addEventListener("end", () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

calling the function :

```
    ReadNews(data) {
    textToSpeech(data.Title)
      .then(textToSpeech(data.Info))
      .then(textToSpeech("Would You like me to continue?"))
      .then(
        ContinueCON.addEventListener("click", () => {
          textToSpeech(data.Content);
        })
      );
};
```

The first 3 instances (data.title, data.info, and the default message) are all spoken as expected. But on the 4th instance, stops after a few seconds.

Several things I have tried:
I used `window.speechSynthesis.speaking` right after the sound stopped working, and it printed true(which is very bizarre)

**1st Edit** (Yet to be solved)

```
Changed the code by the comments below 
export function textToSpeech(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.voice = voices[6];
    msg.lang = "en";
    msg.text = text;
    speechSynthesis.cancel(msg);
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    msg.addEventListener("end", () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Async was unnecessary and also "clean" the "Speak" queue (by using cancel)

```
ReadNews(data) {
    textToSpeech(data.Title)
      .then(() => textToSpeech(data.Info))
      .then(() => textToSpeech("Would You like me to continue?"))
      .then(() =>
        ContinueCON.addEventListener("click", () => {
          textToSpeech(data.Content);
        })
      );
  },
};
```

I invoked the return value immediately instead of waiting for a resolve and then running the next line of text.
Problem is yet to be solved.

Comment: `.then` accepts a function, not a Promise

Comment: textToSpeech(text) is a function , having a promise inside of it

Comment: You're invoking the function immediately, then passing its return value to `.then`.

Comment: didn't notice that! you are right ty a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues with your code, which are causing the speech to all get queued up right away, without waiting. But speechSynthesis is supposed to handle that automatically, so it's not clear to me how they would cause what you're seeing. Still, i'll point them out in case they're causing your problem in a subtle way that i can't identify.

The first issue is that your `textToSpeech` function doesn't return the promise it creates. A promise is implicitly returned since it's an `async` function, but that promise will not wait for the speech to finish. The fix for this is to add a return in (and you can also remove `async` if you wish, since you're not awaiting anything)

```
export function textToSpeech(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.voice = voices[6];
    msg.lang = "en";
    msg.text = text;
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    msg.addEventListener("end", () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Secondly, ReadNews is not waiting for the promises to finish. `.then(textToSpeech(data.Info))` means "immediately call textToSpeech, passing in data.Info, and then whatever it returns pass that into `.then`". Instead, you want to pass a function into `.then`, so that the function will be called once the previous promise has resolved:

```
ReadNews(data) {
  textToSpeech(data.Title)
    .then(() => textToSpeech(data.Info))
    .then(() => textToSpeech("Would You like me to continue?"))
    .then(
      () => ContinueCON.addEventListener("click", () => {
        textToSpeech(data.Content);
      })
    );
}
```

Or with async/await:

```
async ReadNews(data) {
  await textToSpeech(data.Title);
  await textToSpeech(data.Info);
  await textToSpeech("Would you like me to continue?");
  ContinueCON.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textToSpeech(data.Content);
  })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem, with that being said your help was absolutely amazing! I didn't notice I am returning the value of the function and not the actual promise.
About the function, I did delete the async right after posting it realizing it has no effect :) I have also added speechSynthesis.cancel(msg); so that the text won't keep reading even after switching tabs.

Comment: Darn. Not surprised it didn't fix your issue, but i was hoping.